# Получить банан - откуда пошло выражение?

Tags: значение-слов, смысл

Здравствуйте! Откуда пошло выражение "получить банан" в смысле "получить плохую оценку"?

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, так бананами обезьян кормят.   Вот и сравнение.

Бывает и баранку ставят, вдвойне обидно. А еще и кол, хоть кол на голове теши.
Уд и неуд, сокращения с подтекстом.

Answer (score 0):

Бананом называлась двойка, а не всякая плохая оценка. Вот в отношении почему... Тут история древняя, уходит чуть ли не в дореволюционные гимназические времена. Тогда точно было банан - двойка. Потом уже обобщили на единицы и неуды вообще.

Дальше можно только догадываться. Как вариант. Была такая идея, ставить вместо числовых буквенные оценки. А - единица, Б - двойка и т.д. Это точно было. И вот якобы из этого Б получился банан.

Видел другие версии, но они как-то совсем надуманные...

Answer (score -2):

Это смотря где получить "банан". На футболе? Значит, завалили бананами,
точно так же, как товарища Хрущёва кукурузой.

Comment: Николай, старайтесь писать более подробные и аргументированные  ответы и не злоупотребляйте капсом,

Comment: @Серж, думаю автор здесь имел в виду жаргонное "завафлили", поэтому не уверен, что ваша правка уместна.Впрочем как и весь ответ Николая.

Comment: Марк, зафафлить - значит испортить, испачкать. разве можно бананами что-то испачкать, испортить? А как тогда понять: ''точно так же, как товарища Хрущёва кукурузой''.?

Comment: В любом случае ответ Николая неуместен, и сама правка не имеет большого значения. Если пост не удалят, может, автор сам прокомментирует, что он имел в виду.

Comment: @Серж,  "вафлить" имеет ещё значение "миньет", отсюда и ассоциации с бананами и кукурузой.